# Why do Swift standard libraries need to be copied and embedded in every Swift app?

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

I don't understand why XCode can't use system frameworks for the Swift standard libraries, why do they need to be copied with every iOS app that uses Swift? These take up 90% of the space of my apps.

EDIT: This is not a duplicate, I understand why my app is so big. I don't understand why we can't just use system frameworks (at least when targeting >= iOS 8).